# Why Android Studio won't install my app on my phone

Tags: android, compilation, installation, offline

That is the error I get. I don't know why. I am connected. Well at this point I don't know if it refers to another kind of "offline" stuff. 
I didn't find any answers to this specific error

> 09/19 02:49:11: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-J710MN. Installation did
>   not succeed. The application could not be installed. Installation
>   failed due to: 'device offline'

Comment: have you enabled the developer option, have you put the USB mode into the debug mode?

Comment: on your device, have you set "file transfer"? when, you connect a device to PC, it set USB mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for this behaviour. Either your Samsung device is faulty or this is an adb issue. To confirm, enter this command into your terminal while your Samsung device is connected:

```
adb devices
```

If the result returns the name of your Samsung device, then there's probably a problem with the Samsung device.

However, if your terminal does not recognize this command, it means you have to install Samsung adb driver on your computer. This way, your computer would easily recognize your Samsung device. For Windows, there are a ton of links out there where you can download Samsung adb driver; I have not verified any of them, so you might have to do the search by yourself. Nevertheless, I hope you understand the problem now.

I hope this helps.

Merry coding!

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the following codes in the terminal and share the result?

`adb devices`

You can also try this method
`adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`

Comment: Hi, what is your operating system?

Comment: Windows 10. I don't know how but it solved by itself. I just closed Android Studio, restarted my PC and then it worked fine. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

GO to avd manager now you are able to see installed avd. from that actions select wipe data, and run your project. this Worked for me.